# Hash hostname into a color

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, colors

I like to make sure I'm logged into the right host by having a specific color for each host. I copy my `.bashrc` around to different hosts, and edit it with a different color for each one.

However, I would like to not have to manually edit the color on each host, but instead automatically populate the colors for my bash prompt on each host, with a distinctive one for each hostname.

I'm imagining a command in `.bashrc` that gets the hostname, turns it into a unique color, and sets it to be the bash prompt color.

**Question:** How can I hash the hostname into a color in bash?

It might even make a judgment about the set of reasonable colors based on the terminal background color.

Comment: Just write a `case` statement on the contents of `hostname` (which means you have to edit your .bashrc once with an entry for each host, but then you can copy it to all hosts). Making a "reasonable" choice automatically isn't trivial (what colors look well on what background is an art), and you will probably not like the result. But of course you can hash the hostname in some way and use this as a color.

Comment: Again, you might not like the result, but it would be relatively trivial to hash the first or last 3 figures of the IP address, straight to RGB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this might not get a "nice" color based on background, but it should work, assuming the default background color is always color `0`:

```
tput setaf $(hostname | sum | awk -v ncolors=$(infocmp -1 | expand | sed -n -e "s/^ *colors#\([0-9][0-9]*\),.*/\1/p") 'ncolors>1 {print 1 + ($1 % (ncolors - 1))}')
```

To break this down:

- `tput` - output a terminal control string
- `setaf` - the terminal control string; in this case, `set ANSI foreground`
- `$(...)` - BASH nestable command substitution for the color parameter

  - `hostname` - get the hostname
  - `sum` - calculate a simple checksum on the hostname
  - `awk`...
  - `-v ncolors=$(...)` - set the AWK variable `ncolors` to the value of the command substitution within `$(...)`

    - `infocmp -1` - display the terminal information about the current terminal type with 1 parameter per line
    - `expand` - expand tabs to spaces to make the `sed` script a bit easier
    - `sed -n -e "s/^ *colors#\([0-9][0-9]*\),.*/\1/p"` - extract the value of the integer `colors` terminal capability
  - `'ncolors>1 {...}'` - the awk script, which runs the `{...}` code only if `ncolors` is greater than 1

    - `print 1 + ($1 % (ncolors - 1))` - take the absolute`$1` (field 1 of the input, which is coming from `sum`, which means `$1` is the checksum value), find its remainder after being divided by `(ncolors - 1)` (which has the effect of limiting it to the range `0` through `(ncolors - 2)`), then add `1` and print it.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in `context-color`, which I've put together based on J Earls answer: https://github.com/ramnes/context-color

It's a simple script that, when executed, outputs a color based on a command output's hash. With it installed somewhere in your `$PATH`, you could do something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```bash
export PS1="$(context-color -p)$PS1\[\e[0m\]"
```

(where `--prompt/-p` is the switch so that the color is escaped for prompts, and `\[\e[0m\]` the escape sequence to reset color)

By default, the command used to generate the hash is `whoami; hostname`. If you just want the color to change according to the hostname, you can change the `$CC_CONTEXT` variable environment (`export CC_CONTEXT="hostname"`) or simply use the `--context/-c` option (`context-color -c "hostname"`).

See below for an example:

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi ramnes; link only questions are strongly discouraged (even if 'based off' another answer). Please have a read of [how to recommend software in my answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: You're right, thanks for the reminder. I've edited the answer, it should be better now. Please tell me if you feel it's still not enough.

Comment: Much improved :) I added your nifty gif too, hope you don't mind!

Comment: You're very welcome. I took advantage of your edit request to also edit my README. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: @FrankGroeneveld Thanks for the kind words!